# Need help moving fedora 35 system from intel to AMD motherboard

Tags: fedora, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

I had 2 fedora 35 systems, one on an intel i9 and the other on an AMD 5600G. The motherboard with the AMD chip failed and destroyed the contents of the boot drive in the process.

I have replaced the motherboard and would like to replicate the details of the intel install on the AMD machine to save all of the reconfiguration work.

I have cloned the drive from the intel box but when I boot in on the AMD box it stops at the maintenance login prompt. I have tried to continue with a regular login but just get a black screen. I suspect some issue related to video drivers but lack the experience to know what it might be.

I assume that there are some commands that I could run after logging into maintenance mode that would restore the system's sanity but I have no idea what to do next.

Any help and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl` + `alt` + `F2` should give you an alternate `root` shell, where you could run `nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, which permits to comment out the (not so matching) video driver.
Then after a `reboot` you could swap out the video driver and assign it in `xorg.conf`.

The output of `demsg` is of interest, because it shows when drivers fail to load.
Also `Xorg.0.log` may show some `EE` lines, which may provide further clue.

Comment: Thanks,  will try tomorrow

Comment: I have been through the logs and the output from does and journalctl -xb. There are no useful error messages. Booting with nomodeset is no help. Always lands in emergency mode.

Comment: What you write doesn't reflect the instructions provided; please read that slowly... with high probably it loads a kernel module for a device, which is simply "not there"; when reaching until X, the same may happen with the driver for the X server. I mean, there's two possibilities, where it can get stuck.